# Exercise Variation and Periodisation

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, workout-routines, muscle-gain, hypertrophy

I guess I can say it is widly known to change your workout routine from time to time (may that be to focus more on certain muscles, hit muscles a little different, rule out muscle imbalances or simply to have a new and fun routine).

To give an example, I'm talking about switching e.g. BB Bench Press, OHP or Squats (for simplicity referred to as variant A in the following) with exercises like DB (Incline) Bench Press, DB OHP or Lunges/Split Squats (variant B).

Now when trying to implement said switches in exercises, **which of the two following workout routines** (obviously simplified) **would be more efficient** in terms of muscle gains and hypertrophy considering the mentioned above reasoning:

Routine 1:

- Push Day 1 (in a Push-Pull scenario) consists of training with exercises of variant A
- Push Day 2 in the same week however consists of training with exercises of variant B
- following this routine for let's say 4 months or so

Routine 2:

- both Push Days consist of training with exercises of variant A for about 2 months
- after that Push Days consist of training with exercises of variant B for another 2 months (to match that 4 months of routine 1)

Obviously in order to compare these two routines properly we assume the volume and training intensity are the same aswell as how often we train.